scikit-surprise installation in windows
Installation of scikit-surprise using pip in my project file, gives me an error like 'Error originates from subprocess'.
Then I tried to install it globally using conda. And installed it in the base directory. Yet, I couldn't ensure that it's global.
I tried installing using pip install scikit-surprise and also pip install scikit-surprise==1.1.4, a compatible version for python3.12. But then I'm getting this error.
(venv) PS A:\python\app19-movie-recommendation> pip install scikit-surprise==1.1.4
Collecting scikit-surprise==1.1.4
  Using cached scikit_surprise-1.1.4.tar.gz (154 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.2.0 in a:\python\app19-movie-recommendation\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise==1.1.4) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.5 in a:\python\app19-movie-recommendation\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise==1.1.4) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.6.0 in a:\python\app19-movie-recommendation\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise==1.1.4) (1.14.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-surprise
  Building wheel for scikit-surprise (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for scikit-surprise (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [115 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\accuracy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\builtin_datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\trainset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
      copying surprise\model_selection\search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
      copying surprise\model_selection\split.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
      copying surprise\model_selection\validation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
      copying surprise\model_selection\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\baseline_only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\knns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\predictions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\random_pred.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      running egg_info
      writing scikit_surprise.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to scikit_surprise.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to scikit_surprise.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to scikit_surprise.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to scikit_surprise.egg-info\top_level.txt
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      reading manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found under directory 'surprise'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.md'
      writing manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-50yqjas6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:218: _Warning: Package 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying surprise\similarities.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\similarities.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms      
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms        
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms    
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms      
      copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
      running build_ext
      building 'surprise.similarities' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-surprise
Failed to build scikit-surprise
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (scikit-surprise)

And then I installed it using
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise 

in conda prompt, I installed it in my base folder and not in the project directory. Even though, installing in the base folder (not sure is it global) I could import it in my project file and saying its not installed. I'm using VS code and wanted to import Dataset.
Also I tried installing various version in my venv, do I need to install degraded versions of python to work with? I want to work in the VS code itself without creating any other files. Kindly let me know the possible solutions.

You have to install Microsoft Build Tools for c++. Here more info about installation.
